# C# - Is there a way to call a static method of a generic type in a class?

Tags: c#, class, static, static-methods

Example:

```
Public class a<T> where T: containsStatic
{
    public void func()
    {
        T.StaticMethod();
    }

}
```

Is it possible? And if not is there another way to do it?

EDIT: 
it gives me the error: "'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the current context."
why is that? is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How can you know, that type `T` contains a `StaticMethod`?

Comment: `System.Reflection` is the way to go.

Comment: You are right i corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I forsee with this is how do you *guarantee* that `T` supports `StaticMethod`?

However if you are sure that `StaticMethod` will always exist on `T`, you can use reflection to accomplish this fairly simply:

```
using System.Reflection;

public void func()
{
    var staticMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("StaticMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    staticMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: I added the condition, is there another way now?

Comment: @NoamSimon If (from your example) `containsStatic` contains the static method then it will work.

Comment: _If_ you use this solution I would add error handling since you'll get a vague `NullReferenceException` if the type does not have a static method by that name, and you'll get a different exception if it has one with that name but with a different number of parameters.

Comment: Martin, it actually doesn't work, it gives me this error: "'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the current context". what is the possible problem?

Comment: @NoamSimon You haven't put `func` in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we wave a magic wand and you can do that now. Assume a type `C`:

```cs
public class C
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

How would this:

```
public class A<T> where T : C
{
    public void Func()
    {
        T.Foo();
    }

}
```

Be any different from:

```cs
public class A<T> where T : C
{
    public void Func()
    {
        C.Foo();
    }
}
```

It would not. It *would have to be* the same method being called. A static method call is generated statically (yeah, I know) when the method's code gets generated. The compiler seeing `T.Foo()` wouldn't possibly be able to insert any other call than `C.Foo()` there.

So you can't even express that in C#'s grammar, [a type parameter is disallowed by the spec in such a context](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/types.md#type-parameters):

> A type parameter cannot be used in a member access ([Member access](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#member-access)) or type name ([Namespace and type names](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/basic-concepts.md#namespace-and-type-names)) to identify a static member or a nested type.

If you want to *dynamically* call a static method depending on `T`'s value at runtime, refer to @Martin 's reflection solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any static method, if it does not depend on the Generic Type.
If you have a class like

```
 public class Test<T>
 {
        public static int Result => 5;
 }
```

You can call

```
 int n = Test<int>.Result;
```

at any place you want, and it is not important what type you actually insert, since any type will do the same

```
 int n = Test<string[]>.Result;
```

will do the very same thing.

If your function depends on T like in

```
    public class Test1<T>
    {
        public static void Action(T param)
        {

        }
    }
```

You can use

```
  Test1<int>.Action(8);
```

At any place you want.

Also inside other generic classes:

```
    public  class OtherClass<T> 
    {
        public void Method(T param)
        {
            Test1<T>.Action(param);
        }
    }
```

But most often it is possible to write a generic function in a non-generic class like

```
    public class Test2
    {
        public static void Action<T>(T param)
        {

        }
    }
```

This works at any place in the Program

```
   Test2.Action("string");
   Test2.Action(9);
```

You can put this function in any class you want, since it's static. There is no need to put this function in a generic class.